# Running ISC DHCP SERVER6 for IPV6 on ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, dhcpv6

I am using ISC DHCP SERVER6 for ipv6 on ubuntu machine.

My requirement is
1. I am using two ubuntu machines. Dhcpv6 server is running on one machine and dhcpv6 client is running on another machine.
2.vendor class (option 16) is sent from client.
3.In Server side, according to vendor class (option 16) , corresponding vendor opts (option 17) should be sent from dhcpv6 server
4.Can you please give me , sample server side configuration for ISC DHCPv6.

My current Dhcpv6 server configuration:

```
authoritative;

default-lease-time 14400;

max-lease-time 86400;

log-facility local7;

option space RAKU code width 1 length width 1 hash size 3;

option RAKU.server-name code 2 = text;


subnet6 2012:db8:bad:a55::/64 {

    option dhcp6.name-servers 2012:4860:4860::8888, 2012:4860:4860::8844;

    option dhcp6.domain-search "osi.io";

    range6 2012:db8:bad:a55::100 2012:db8:bad:a55::199;

    range6 2001:db8:bad:a55::/64 temporary;


class "vendor-classes" {

  match option vendor-class-identifier;

}



subclass "vendor-classes" "raku" {

  vendor-option-space RAKU;

}



option RAKU.server-name "RakutenWlc";
}
```

and in my client side , `openwrt dhclient` is running by using below syntax

```
./odhcp6c -V 72616b75 -N none -ev enp0s3
```

here in client, vendor class is sent by including option -V in above syntax.

Can you please tell me,if you find any mistakes in my above configuration files. I tried with above configuration, still vendor specific is not sent from server. Please help me to find out answer.

Thanks,
Durga K
~
~

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include current server and client configuration.

Comment: I have added current server configuration. please provide your comments.

Comment: > how will i install ISC DHCP server version 4.4.0 in ubuntu 16.04 < you won't, unless you are going to compile it yourself (which I don't recommend) or unless you use a repository that has newer versions of `isc-dhcp-server` backported to Xenial.  And I don't know of any such repositories or PPAs either